# How to exclude a dependency coming from parent in POM file

Tags: maven

I am pulling in dependencies from a parent and need most of the dependencies in there.
But I also wish to be able to exclude 2 dependencies entirely. I am not able to edit the parent
thus this needs to be excluded from my POM file. Is this even possible? I've seen examples for overrides and quite a bit of suggestion to fix the parent POM which as mentioned, I can't do at this time.

Using Maven 3.3.x

My POM file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.stuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>our-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</parent>

<!-- other dependencies and build and plugins -->
```

The parent in above pulls in following plugins which I wish to exclude entirely.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${some.version}</version>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${some.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way around this? Please advice. Thanks.

Tried with Thiago's suggestion, same outcome.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>maven-checkstyle-plugin</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> 
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just skip the plugin executions?

You could set the `skip` parameter of both plugins to true.

Comment: That works and so does the phase none. Trying to see which is the preferred / correct option to go with in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ID_AS_IN_PARENT</id> <!-- id is necessary sometimes -->
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Tried this suggestion and provided id as maven-checkstyle-plugin. Doesn't make a difference. The check style still present. The example I tried added to question above for reference.